# Excel generating several .xar files upon computer restart

Tags: windows-7, excel-2007

My computer has an update process that auto-restarts it around 3 am. Sometimes, upon restart, a number of .xar files are generated which Excel tries & fails to open, preventing it from executing automated processes I've set up for the morning.

How do I prevent the .xar files from being generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.xar files are Auto recovery files, probably created because your restart doesn't gracefully exit Excel.

You can disable auto recover on a workbook by going to the office button, excel options, save, AutoRecover exceptions for: and then checking "Disable AutoRecover for this workbook only".

If you do this for the workbooks that you're update process uses it should prevent the failure you're experiencing.